# Grails:Groovy:SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: grails, groovy, xmlhttprequest, ssl-certificate, httpbuilder

I want to hit an xml request to a url while running the code in my local system it is working well i have created a war file and deployed the same in server,but while running in server getting an exception `'javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated'`
i have used groovy http builder

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)
          http.auth.basic('username', 'password')
        try {               
            http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.TEXT) {
                        req->
                            headers.accept = "application/xml"
                            body = request //xml request
                            response.success = {
                                        resp,reader ->
                                            Response =  reader.text
                            }
            }
        }
        catch(HttpResponseException ex) {
             println ex;
        }
```

how can i solve this problem in this case..?

Comment: Try [this blog](http://blog.nerdability.com/2013/01/tech-how-to-fix-sslpeerunverifiedexcept.html) and following links having similar exception.   [Groovy http builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/ssl.html)  [**SO1**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https), [**SO2**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837015/apache-http-client-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authentica), [**SO3**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474313/java-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated).

Answer (score 6):

**Workaround:** The following answer provides a workaround for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25076888/782034

> Just found out that new version (0.7.1) of HttpBuilder introduces
>   method:
>
> ```
> ignoreSSLIssues()
> ```
>
> This solves all problems regarding invalid SSL certificates (of course
>   you have to be aware that it also decrease security).
>
> More information about this method:
>   http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/ssl.html (section
>   at the bottom)

*i.e.*

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)
http.ignoreSSLIssues()
```

**Solution:** If you want to do things the 'proper' way, checkout the other solutions regarding importing the server's certificates. e.g. [SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12961570/782034)

Comment: I'm using `ignoreSSLIssues()` and still getting the SSLPeerUnverifiedException.

Answer (score 3):

If you use ignoreSSLIssues() but still get same exception.

Just add latest httpclient into Gradle/Maven

> compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'

[Can't use ignoreSSLIssues in HttpBuilder version 0.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886197/cant-use-ignoresslissues-in-httpbuilder-version-0-7-1/43888612#43888612)