# HttpBuilder: "peer not authenticated", works fine in Postman

Tags: curl, paypal, groovy, postman, httpbuilder

I'm experiencing a problem accessing a paypal (sandbox) API. The code

```
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

HTTPBuilder http = new HTTPBuilder( 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1' )
http.auth.basic clientId, secret
http.headers.Accept = 'application/json'
http.headers[ 'Accept-Language' ] = 'en_US'
http.request( POST ){
  uri.path = '/oauth2/token'
  requestContentType = URLENC
  body = 'grant_type=client_credentials'

  response.success = { resp, json ->
    println json
  } 
}
```

on my local computer gives

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

If i run a `curl`

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -H "Authorization: Basic {base64 text}=" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I get:

```
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

If I run the same query in `Postman`, it runs smoothly.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

If I add `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`, the following debug info appears

> http-bio-8880-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
>   http-bio-8880-exec-3, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
>   http-bio-8880-exec-3
>   , RECV TLSv1 ALERT:
>   fatal, 
>   handshake_failure
>   http-bio-8880-exec-3, called closeSocket()
>   http-bio-8880-exec-3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: Have you tried `-k` switch for curl?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692780/grailsgroovysslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated

Comment: @tim_yates I tried `ignoreSSLIssues()` with no luck

Comment: @Opal `-k` changes nothing

Comment: @injecteer any steps/instructions to reproduce?

Comment: @Opal you need to have a sandbox paypal app to get a hold of `client id` and `secret`. then you can run the `curl` / `postman` query as per https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token

Comment: @Opal I can send you my credentials for testing as well

Comment: @injecteer, sure. Possible with working sample along? You can find me on twitter, e.g. twitter.com/czaszo

Comment: @injecteer, have you finally worked it out?

Comment: @Opal It looks like the machnies that fail to dispatch the curl (like AWS ec-2 micro) do not support `TLS1.2` and I have no idea yet on how to upgrade them