# Can't use ignoreSSLIssues in HttpBuilder version 0.7.1

Tags: groovy, ssl-certificate, httpbuilder

Java 8 |
Groovy Language |
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA | 
Gradle 3

I have problem with SSL issue

**Code:**

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

def client = new RESTClient()
client.ignoreSSLIssues()
def result = client.get(uri: "https://sacvo76l6b.execute-api.ap-northeast-
1.amazonaws.com/")
```

It throws below exception

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
>
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
>     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
>     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1066)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1044)
>     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)
>     at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.get(RESTClient.java:119)
>     at Test.getAuthCode_(Test.groovy:53)

Although I'm using `ignoreSSLIssues()`, it seems like not work for me.

I also download version 0.7.2 to verify this problem, but it's also same problem

PS1: Uri works fine for me if i use Postman

PS2: HttpURLConnection library also works for me

Could you have any idea? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated" issue
 I just import lastest version of httpclient to Gradle/Maven

`compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'`

It took me 2 days to resolve. I hope this will be helpful with someone like me.

Comment: In my case the error is sun.security.validator.ValidatorException